# Find all $z = (x, y)$ such that $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all $z = (x, y)$ such that $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$

I just started doing complex numbers and am unsure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Complete the square or use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $z^3 - 1 = (z-1)(z^2+z+1) = 0 \implies z^3 = 1$ , but $z \neq 1$, thus of the three roots of unity, take the non-unity roots.